# quasi-complete separation in Python but not in SAS?

Tags: python, sas

I am constructing a binary logistic regression model using 'proc logistic' in SAS, and the output appears to be error-free with no warning messages. However, when I replicate the same dataset and variables in Python using statsmodels, I encounter an error message indicating possible quasi-complete separation: 'A fraction of 0.20 of observations can be perfectly predicted. This might indicate quasi-separation, and in such cases, some parameters may not be identified.' In light of this discrepancy, I am uncertain about which set of results to trust—those from SAS or from Python. Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: Without seeing the data and the code it's hard to guess. The library, and the way of handling missing values also matter. Please provide if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which results you want. Prediction should be fine and the same independently of how quasi-complete separation is handled.

Parameter estimates and inference may not be valid in either package for some parameters that are only "identified", i.e. estimated in a deterministic way, through the details of the optimization procedure. The true parameters could be infinite or a set of parameters would produce the same predictions.

e.g.
https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them

Statsmodels only checks for perfectly predicted observations and does not try to identify all cases of quasi-complete separation nor it's source. So, there might also be differences across packages in the situations the warning (or exception) is issued.